# Disable Cache For Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Jquery GET**

```
 var inputData = { Years: $("#year").val();};

  $.get('/MyController/GetData, inputData, function (result) {
            alert("Success!, I Got My Data");
           });
```

How to disable the Cache for this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add timestamp to url:

```
$.get('/MyController/GetData?' + $.now(), inputData, function (result) {
    alert("Success!, I Got My Data");
});
```

Or:

```
var inputData = { _: $.now(), Years: $("#year").val()};

$.get('/MyController/GetData', inputData, function (result) {
    alert("Success!, I Got My Data");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try. Will it work if I use this line: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });?

Comment: it will not , coz you still need timestamp for it. referrence : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Zergling actually it will work, because setting cache: false appends timestamp as query param

Comment: @AlexArt. thats what jquery said . Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters

Comment: @Zergling did you miss `$.get` (get is a shortcut that uses HTTP GET request)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of `$.get`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/MyController/GetData",
  data: inputData,    
  cache: false
}).done(function (result) {
        alert("Success!, I Got My Data");
});
```